# javascript - Difference in the way you call alert() and sqrt()?

Tags: javascript

```
window.alert("Hello!");
```

is the same as

```
alert("Hello!");
```

---

```
// Works
Math.sqrt(4);
Math.floor(3.55);
Math.round(2.5);

// Does not work
sqrt(4);
floor(3.55);
round(2.5);
```

Why is this so? When do I need to type the object (such as `Math` or `window`) and when not?

Comment: Difference between alert() and sqrt()? HA ha ha ha...

Comment: Well...I mean the difference in the way you call them

Comment: I know. Thanks for the laugh though :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a browser, properties of `window`, like `alert` or `document`, are global.

That is, `alert` is `window.alert`, and `Math.sqrt` is `window.Math.sqrt`.

> When do I need to type the object (such as Math or window) and when not?

Essentially, if the object is `window`, you don't need to have it. For all other cases, you do.

Comment: @chris97ong, because `document` is not `window`. `document.write` and `window.document.write` work, but `write` does not because `window.write` does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

`Math` is at the same level as `alert` i.e. they both come directly under `window`.

`Math` can be called like `window.Math` the same way you call `window.alert`

Answer (score 0):

The methods of the window object can be called implicitly as this is the default scope in javascript, you can do so explicitly as Window.alert("Hello world"), but this is redundant.

The sqrt() method is not part of the Window object so you have to call it explicitly like so Math.sqrt(). its all about hierarchy